# Front hub motor makes clacking noise only when nut tightened

Tags: repair, electric-bike, noise, motor

I have a Bafang SWXK2 e-bike front hub motor. It has been use for 7 years, about 10 000 km ridden and has worked well so far. But now it is making a clacking noise.

Symptoms:

- Clacking noise synchronized to rotation.
- Loudest with weight on the bike, but audible even with bike upside down.
- Happens both with motor freewheeling and with motor engaged.
- Noise disappears if I loosen the left side nut (opposite side of cable exit).

On the side with problem, I can see a DC6001-2RS bearing inside the motor, against which the anti-rotation washer rests.

Here is a video of it:

[image: Video of problem]

I'll try to open it later and update whether I figure out anything. But if anyone has good guesses of which spare parts to get, or can find any maintenance information, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Missing disc brake screws permit sand to enter the gearing.**

[image: Missing screws]

Back on the first bike I had this motor on, the disc brake screws rubbed against the front suspension fork, so I simply removed them. I did not realize that this left direct holes to the mechanism:

[image: Disc brake screw holes from the other side]

There were a couple of sand particles in the ring gear.

I'm still not sure why loosening the nut affected it, but possibly it permitted the mechanism to move slightly and by pure luck it wouldn't hit the sand.

After a good cleanup, some new grease and plugging the holes, everything seems to work fine again. Fortunately I caught this early enough that there wasn't much damage to the gears.